# I can only use ~30gb out of 512gb on my ssd

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I just got this new laptop, an Asus Vivobook 14 with i5 and an SSD of 512 GB. I finished installing Windows 10 pro using a USB flash drive.

When I wanted to install things, like Google Chrome, WhatsApp, Teams I couldn't.
When I looked in my PC there are drive C (25 GB), E (3 GB) and D (1.9 GB)
When I looked in disk management I saw the rest with 456 GB.
Please help me because I am very confused right now.

[image: disk managment]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of Disk Management window in your question? It will be helpful to detect your issue easily.

Comment: If it is a fresh Windows installation the easiest way would be to install it again and this time to make sure that the disk is erased before you actually start the installation. On a clean disk Windows uses nearly the whole space for it's system partition.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I just added a screenshot, it would mean a lot if you would answer.

Answer (score 0):

The rest of your disk space is not allocated. It's just sitting there unused.
You can right click on that region and select New Simple Volume to create a new partition.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-and-format-a-hard-disk-partition-bbb8e185-1bda-ecd1-3465-c9728f7d7d2e

Although I recommend that you merge that region with drive D because it appears to be too small and useless.

In fact, it's even better that you completely reallocated the entire disk space (make a backup of your Drivers first!).
Use a bootable partition manager and recreate your drives. You can check out this one for example:
https://gparted.org/

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: The disk is allocated.  It just doesn’t have a drive letter assigned to it.  This answer should be edited and corrected

Answer (score 0):

There is something strange here. Disk Management shows two physical disks - the 512GB you are expecting and a 32GB drive. You have installed windows on the 32GB drive.
Have you got an SD card or a USB drive connected?

Comment: @VladAriesan - Edit your question